# How does this Ruby code work - if-stmt with ranges ?

Tags: ruby

I'm currently learning Ruby and I can't seem to wrap around what `if /start/../end` does... Help?

```
while gets
  print if /start/../end/
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you're new to Ruby, it's first worth taking note that you're dealing with Regular Expressions (regex) in the example - anything that is delimited between two forward slashes:

```
/start/   # a regular expression literal
```

Regular Expressions are a powerful way of matching a certain combination of letters from a larger string.

```
"To start means to begin." =~ /start/  #=> true, because 'start' is in the string.
```

The double dot notation is the flip-flop operator, a controversial construct probably inherited from Perl and not usually recommended to be used because it can lead to confusion.

It means the following:
It will collectively evaluate to false until the left hand operand is true. At which point it will collectively evaluate to true. However it will only remain true until the right hand operand evaluates to true - at which point it will again evaluate collectively to false.

Using your above example therefore:

```
while gets
 print if /start/../end/
end
```

1. Until 'start' is entered in, the entire expression is false, and nothing is printed.
2. When 'start' is input, the entire expression is true, therefore EVERYTHING input after this point will also be printed out. (despite not being 'start')
3. As soon as 'end' is input, the entire expression evaluates to false, and nothing from that point on is printed out.

Comment: Regex are not necessarily created using `/`. They can also be created using `%r` and methods in the Regexp class.

Comment: While `/foo/../bar/` is not well known, it is remarkably concise and succinct, and a great way to grab blocks of text, especially when reading from a file. I've seen people try to replace it with methods, but the resulting code was a mess. Yes, it collides visually with the `..` range operator, but its usefulness makes it worth knowing.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer is very helpful! There wasn't any mention of the flip-flop operator in the book yet there the code example still used it so I was thoroughly confused!

Answer (score 3):

It's called the flip-flop operator. You can read more at "[Ruby flip-flop operator](http://matousek.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/ruby-flip-flop-operator/)".